# oracle Two table query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables CRDDET and CUSTDET on oracle DB 
I want to get two columns from CRDDET ( PAN, EXPDATE )
and 1 column from CUSTDET ( CUSTCODE )
and they share the same values in CRDDET.CUSTDET_ID and CUSTDET.ID

can anyone plz help me and sorry for my poor explanation because of my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is your expected query,

```
select C1.PAN, C1.EXPDATE, C2.CUSTCODE from CRDDET C1
inner join CUSTDET C2
on (C1.CUSTDET_ID = C2.ID);
```